# Convert C++ struct to C# struct

Tags: c#, c++, struct, converters

I need to convert a struct to bytes so that I can send or receive it over a network.

Let's say the struct is something like below:

```
struct Info
{
    unsigned int Age;
    char Name[];
};
```

I have the equivalent struct in C# sharp which is:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Info
{
    public uint Age;
    public string Name;
};
```

To convert the C# struct to byte I use the this method:

```
    public Byte[] GetBytes(Info info)
    {
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(info);
        byte[] arr = new byte[size];
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(info, ptr, true);
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

        return arr;
    }
```

And to Convert the received bytes to C++ struct I use this method:

```
Info GetInfo(const char* bytes)
{
    Info info;
    memcpy(&info, bytes, sizeof(info));

    return info;
}
```

My problem is that the Age field of the struct converts very well but the Name field never is what has been sent.

**Update**

I can easily convert a string to bytes using the code below and send it from c# client app to c++ server app.

```
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text + "\0");
```

so I decided to change the C# struct as below:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Info
{
    public uint Age;
    public byte[] Name;
};
```

but in this case the GetBytes() method crashes.

Comment: Could you offer some information on why you need a struct but moreover why you need to convert it to bytes?

Comment: A bit difficult; can you see what's transmitted "on the wire"?

Comment: I'm doing socket programming. The server is written in C++ and the client in C# and the message sent or received between then is a structure.

Comment: If age works but name does not perhaps you are dealing with some sort of character set encoding mismatch.

Comment: And what it might be @BradD?

Comment: The C++ code isn't using `CMsg`. I'm confused. In any case, the size of the struct in C++ is implementation defined, I believe (in particular because you're using the "C struct hack"). The name is of a variable length. In C#, `string` members are just references to the actual strings allocated on the heap, so you'll have to do a lot more legwork than merely copying the struct's bytes, but also those of the string.

Comment: A string is no C# value type, it is a reference type, hence your marshaling fails

Comment: Might help if you included the raw network data from Wireshark (or whatever tool you're using) in the question.

Comment: @Cameron sorry about the struct name. it was a mistake. I think you're right about the string type in C#. What is the solution for this problem?

Comment: It never works right to convert whole structure. You have to do it field-by-field. On c# side you're most likely getting string size as well as string content, while on C++ side there is no length. Plus, on C# side string are Unicode, 16bit per char, while on C++ side they are just chars. I would recommend to use canned solution like http://kentonv.github.io/capnproto/

Comment: I bet if I use only numeric data types in the structure the whole of it will be converted without any problem. I suppose the only problem is the string type and I think there must be a solution for that.

Comment: @user3530012 This won't work with structs with flexible array members.  In your case, `sizeof(Info) == sizeof(unsigned int) == 4`.

Comment: @Cameron: If it was `char Name[0];` (or 1), it would be the struct-hack. As-is, it's a flexible-array-member (and a C99 feature) instead.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Ah, neat, looks like it's actually well-defined. Still needs extra care when marshaling, of course, since `sizeof(CMsg)` won't include the string data.

Answer (score 4):

1. Your C++-structure uses a flexible array member as the last element, which is an extension borrowed from C99:

   In essence, it means that an array of unknown length ends it.
   Because the length is not known, the compiler will, when asked for the structures size, assume **`0`**.
   I somehow doubt that's what you wanted.
2. Your C#-structure has a `string`-member, which is not a value-type.

   Just copying the managed pointer to it like you do is quite nonsensical.

So, what should you do?

#### Define your own wire-format.

- An `unsigned` 32-bit integer will be easily marshalled.
- The string is more difficult. Do you have a sentinel-value never part of the string?
  Or do you have to use / prefer counted strings, in which case you have to decide what type the size will be and marshal that first?

  Also, don't forget the character-set: Prefer UTF-8, though if it's windows-only, UTF-16 little-endian may also be a viable choice.

Comment: Your explanation was really helpful and now I know what the problem is, yet I haven't figure it out what to do with it? Could you be a little more helpful on this?

Comment: Alan just posted two libraries specializing in such.

Answer (score 1):

This can get very complicated very quickly.

You might want to look at some libraries that can help - [Google Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) and [Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/) immediately spring to mind. Both support C++ and C# amongst other languages.

Comment: Thank you. I will test it and let you know the result.